# How can I automatically resolve Git conflicts when merging multiple branches

Tags: git, gitlab, github-actions, elastalert2

**Scenario**

In a Jenkins pipeline, there is a stage that clones a repository, let's call it "alert-repo," updates a file named "test.yml," and pushes it back to a Git repository on a branch, then raises a PR against the "master" branch.

This Jenkins workflow is triggered multiple times in parallel, and every time it creates a branch from "master," makes changes to "test.yml," and raises a PR back to "master."

My objective is to automatically merge all the changes from these PRs into the "master" branch without encountering conflicts.

**Problem**

When I merge the first PR back to "master," subsequent PRs often encounter merge conflicts because all of them are modifying the same file, "test.yml."

For example, if I try to merge branch "b" into "master" after merging branch "a," Git detects conflicts.

I'm seeking a solution to automatically resolve these conflicts and incorporate changes from all the branches without manual intervention.

**What I've Tried**

1. I've attempted to use Git's default merge strategy, but it doesn't consistently achieve the desired results.
2. I've explored the "ours" and "theirs" merge strategies, but they don't fulfill my requirements.
3. Rebase
4. [https://github.com/tibdex/auto-update](https://stackoverflow.com)
5. Putting a github workflow with a hack to slove this but does't help much.

**Goal**

I'm searching for a solution that enables me to automatically merge both branches "a" and "b" into "master" while retaining as many changes as possible without requiring manual intervention. Is this achievable with Git, and if so, how can I accomplish it?

Welcome to other solutions as well.

**Exact User-case**

I am implementing alerting using "elasta-alert" and I have a microservices architecture(200+ apps). I want to give developers the power to add their own alerts in their application Helm values file. Then, in the CI stage, I want to compile all the repository files into a Helm values file for "elasta-alert" and apply it. However, if two CI jobs trigger in parallel, clone the elasta-alert helm chart master branch, and raise PRs updating the same file, merging any PR leads to merge conflicts with other PRs.

Comment: _"I've explored the "ours" and "theirs" merge strategies, but they don't fulfill my requirements."_ - what are your requirements?

Comment: I guess my question really is: if branches "a" and "b" make different modifications to your test.yml file, how would git know which changes it should take in?

Comment: @1615903 I want to keep the changes from all the branches without having the merge conflict. Say I have 1 in my main branch on a file and PR "A" brings 2 and PR "B" brings 3 now I want to have 123 in my main branch.

Comment: @1615903 Agreed, but is there a workaround to solve this?

I am implementing alerting using "elasta-alert," and I have a microservices architecture. I want to give developers the power to add their own alerts in their Helm values file. Then, in the CI stage, I want to compile all the repository files into a Helm values file for "elasta-alert" and apply it. However, if two CI jobs trigger in parallel, clone the master branch, and raise PRs updating the same file, merging any PR may lead to merge conflicts with other PRs that were started.

Comment: There is no automatic conflict resolution feature in git because it's impossible, it will never be implemented. Because it's not a problem ot on a technical level, it's the very nature of that step. Conflicts are choices. Machines just follow instructions, they can't decide. You might want to consider a custom script to automate the very specific recurring conflicts you're facing?

Comment: Makes no sense. If Git could automatically resolve a merge conflict it would not be a merge conflict. "Conflict" literally just means that Git cannot do the merge. Human help is the only option.

Comment: You might be better served by asking how you can avoid conflicts to begin with when designing your particular solution.